# Animate item in container to animate and contain 100% of the container

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I am trying to animate a list of items in a container to transition to 100% height and width of its container once clicked.

I can't seem to figure out a nice way to accomplish this without breaking the layout once setting the item clicked to absolute. Is there a way to retain its position in the layout while absolute and then transition to 100% width and height. As well as transition up and right, if its in say the bottom right of my very basic grid.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="item">Some Content</div>
  <div class="item">Some Content</div>
  <div class="item">Some Content</div>
  <div class="item">Some Content</div>

</div>
```

css:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 420px;
  background: green;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

.item.active {
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

js:

```
var parent = document.querySelector('.container');
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

var manipulateDOM = function(item) {
    //make item animate and contain the entire parent .container.
  item.classList.add('active');

  var height = parent.clientHeight;
  var width = parent.clientWidth;

  item.style.height = height + 'px';
  item.style.width = width + 'px';
};

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        manipulateDOM(event.target);
    });
}
```

or

Heres a jsfiddle of what i've got so far if that helps understand the problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/zyo335qy/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of problems needed to be solved.

- Converting the target div from relative to absolute created a "hole" in the layout, causing all of the later (relative) divs to shift left and/or up to take its place. Thus, rather than simply converting the target div, it had to be cloned, leaving the original to be a place-holder even though it won't be seen. This may, of course, cause problems, depending on what has been copied (e.g. duplicated id's). A more elegant and robust solution would be to remove the target div and re-insert a "dummy" relative div in the same location, but for the sake of simplicity I haven't implemented that here.
- The starting top and left values had to be retrieved from the target element so the animation knows where to start, moving from there to 0,0. This can be accomplished with `offsetTop` and `offsetLeft`.
- For reasons I must admit I don't completely understand (some insightful comments would be helpful), it didn't work to just set the destination top, left, height and width values. They had to be embedded in a `setTimeout`. A delay of 0 ms or even 10 ms worked some but not all of the time. A delay of 50 ms seems to work consistently, but this may need to be tested further.
- The top, left, height and width values had to be adjusted to take the margins into consideration.

***Update**: This solution seems to work in Firefox v44.0.2 (Mac and Windows) and Chrome (Mac v48.0.2564.103 and Windows v48.0.2564.116), but not in Safari (Mac v9.0.3) and Internet Explorer (Windows v11.0.28). To see the correct or incorrect behaviour more clearly, increase the setTimeout delay to, say, 2000 ms.*

```js
var parent = document.querySelector('.container');
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

var manipulateDOM = function(origItem) {
    //make item animate and contain the entire parent .container.
  var item = origItem.cloneNode(true);
  var top = origItem.offsetTop;
  var left = origItem.offsetLeft;
  item.classList.add('active');
  parent.appendChild(item);

  var height = parent.clientHeight;
  var width = parent.clientWidth;
  item.style.top = (top - 5) + 'px';
  item.style.left = (left - 5) + 'px';
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    item.style.top = '0px';
    item.style.left = '0px';
    item.style.height = (height - 10) + 'px';
    item.style.width = (width - 10) + 'px';
  }, 50);
};

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        manipulateDOM(event.target);
    });
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 420px;
  background: green;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

.item.active {
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="item">Some Content A</div>
  <div class="item">Some Content B</div>
  <div class="item">Some Content C</div>
  <div class="item">Some Content D</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.is this what you want.I implemented it for only two divs(only for one and two) and with two different effects.I used jquery with this.just copy, paste and try it.you can implement it for othres like this.if this is not the case tell me.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<style type="text/css">
 .container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 420px;
  background: green;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

.item.active {
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
</style>
<body>


<div class="container">

  <div class="item" id="one">Some Content</div>
  <div class="item" id="two">Some Content</div>
  <div class="item" id="three">Some Content</div>
  <div class="item" id="four">Some Content</div>

</div>
  
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
   
   $("#one").click(function(){
    $(this).animate({width:"100%",height:"410px"});
    $("#two,#three,#four").hide();
   });

   $("#two").click(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut().animate({width:"100%",height:"410px"}).fadeIn(1000);
    $("#one,#three,#four").hide();
   });
 
  });
 
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```